# Excel VBA Userform Combobox - Load Multiple Columns Values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using this code to load values of used range in column `C`. This works fine, however I need to also load values in columns `E` and `G` inside the combobox separated by a "-" so for example each combobox entry will read `"Row 1 Col C value - Row 1 Col E value - Row 1 Col G value"`.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ws = mysheet
        lastrow = ws.Columns("C").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        tag_combo.List = ws.Range("C" & ws.Range("start_row_pu").Row + 1 & ":" & "C" & lastrow).Value2
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example call joining column values**

As close as possible to your original post you can read all values into a 1-based 2-dim temporary array, join 1st, 3rd and 5th column values by `&` and assign them back to the comboboxe's `.List` property:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
        lastrow = ws.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim v       As Variant
        v = ws.Range("C" & ws.Range("start_row_pu").Row + 1 & ":" & "G" & lastrow).Value2

        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)            ' join column values C, E, G
            v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & " - " & v(i, 3) & " - " & v(i, 5)
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve v(1 to Ubound(v), 1 to 1)   ' redimension temporary array to 1 column 
        ComboBox1.List = v                         ' assign array back to .List property
End Sub
```

**Further notes due to question in comment**

After having assigned range data (e.g. `C2:G4711`) to a 2-dimensioned 1-based variant array `v` you have to loop through the 1-based array data now, where

- `LBound(v)` always starts from *"row"* `1` in a 1-based array (so callede lower boundary) and
- `UBound(v)` returns the upper boundary, *e.g. `4710` (=4711 - 2 + 1 as starting from the second row)*  *"rows"*;

now you refer to column **`C`** data in the original range via *"column"* index `1` of the variant array, i.e. `v(i, 1)`, to **`E`** via index `3`: `v(i, 3)`, to **`G`** via index `5`: `v(i, 5)`. The above example **joins** the 1st, the 3rd and the 5th value in the array *column* items via the `&` connector and assigns the resulting string back to the first array column thus (over)writing the already read in data of range column `C`.

Eventually you have to redimension the original 5 array columns to only one in order to represent your wanted data row connected now by `" - "`.

Comment: ok this works as expected but what is the boundcolumn? I just want to be the value in column C